# Swift Cast AnyObject to Block

Tags: ios, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

So I am using the Salesforce SDK and built bridging headers for the entire SDK.

They provide a block syntax which hasn't translated into the most usable code.  For instance,

```
func sendRESTRequest(request: SFRestRequest!, failBlock: SFRestFailBlock!, completeBlock: AnyObject!)
```

The complete block is AnyObject!.  I was able to get around this with

```
var block : @objc_block (dataResponse :AnyObject!) -> Void = { dataResponse in //I handle the response}
restService.sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: { (error :NSError!) -> Void in

        }, completeBlock: unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject.self))
```

So far this works fine.  However, now I am trying to build unit testing for this code.  I have created a mock class for SFRestAPI which is the class where the function "sendRESTRequest" resides.  For testing purposes, I am trying to mock out the completeBlock: parameter by passing mock "data" that would be returned from the REST service.

```
class MockSFRestAPI : SFRestAPI {

    override func sendRESTRequest(request: SFRestRequest!, failBlock: SFRestFailBlock!, completeBlock: AnyObject!) {
        //Convert complete block into a closure and pass in some test data
    }
}
```

The issue is, I am unable to cast AnyObject! to a block like I was able to cast the block to AnyObject like above.

Some of my attempts have been:

```
var block = completeBlock as @objc_block (AnyObject! -> Void)
var block2: (AnyObject! -> Void) = unsafeBitCast(completeBlock, (@objc_block (AnyObject! -> Void)))
```

There have been many more attempts, but these are the only two that seem relatively sane.  So, is this possible in Swift?  The issue seems to be that I cannot provide a closure "type" to the second parameter of the unsafeBitCast method.  I want to turn it into a closure so I can call it in my mock method and pass in some fake data.

Comment: I have the same isuue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle this situation is to create your own typealias for your block:

```
 typealias MyFunBlock = @objc_block (dataResponse :AnyObject!) -> Void;
```

Then you can use that to unsafebitcast:

```
var block: MyFunBlock = unsafeBitCast(completeBlock, MyFunBlock.self) as MyFunBlock;
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. Very easy to miss a character in wrapping/unwrapping the options. This makes it much nicer to track in the code.