# Call Objective-C block stored in NSDictionary from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Intended Result: I create a block, store it in an NSDictionary, pass the dictionary to a Swift class, retrieve the block from the dictionary, and call the block.

Actual Result: Retrieving the block from the dictionary results in an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

Sample Code Obj-C View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    void (^completionHandler)() = ^() {
        [self printBlahBlah];
    };

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"blah":completionHandler};
    Nav *nav = [Nav new];
    [nav done:dict];
}

-(void)printBlahBlah { NSLog(@"BlahBlah"); }
```

Sample Code from Nav Swift class:

```
@objc public class Nav : NSObject {

    @objc public func done(dict: NSDictionary){
        let block = dict["blah"] as! ()->Void //EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
        block()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So this works:

```
@objc public class Nav : NSObject {

    typealias MyFunBlock = @convention(block) () -> Void;

    @objc public func done(dict: NSDictionary){
        let block = unsafeBitCast(dict["blah"], BoolBlock.self) as BoolBlock?
        block?()
    }
}
```

But the documentation for unsafeBitCast says:

```
/// Returns the bits of `x`, interpreted as having type `U`.
///
/// - Warning: Breaks the guarantees of Swift's type system; use
///   with extreme care.  There's almost always a better way to do
///   anything.
///
@warn_unused_result
public func unsafeBitCast<T, U>(x: T, _: U.Type) -> U
```

I feel like I don't want to use this.

Credit really goes to this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376909/1366911

Comment: I think in the maturation of Swift we'll see the need for `unsafeBitCast` go away here. Note that the `@convention` is important here.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is the block is being released prior to its use in Swift.  Fix by copying it into the collection...

```
// ...
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"blah":[completionHandler copy]};
// ...
```